# create a pdf from a pyinstaller python frozen code

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I would like to create a pdf file from Python, with seaborn plot, image and text. 
In jupyter notebook the lines : `fig1.savefig("export-sns-plot.png")` and `pdf.output("add_image.pdf")` does indeed export an image and a pdf file including the image.

But when I freeze the code using Pyinstaller and lauch the exe nothing happens, help..

Thank you

```
# librairies import
import pandas as pd
from fpdf import FPDF
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

#dataset import
outils1 = pd.read_csv("projet.csv")
#colums rename
df1 = outils1.rename(columns = {"Unnamed: 0": "Axes","Unnamed: 1":"Reponse"})

#plot generation
x1= df1.Axes
y1= df1.Reponse
sns_plot1 = sns.barplot(x1,y1,data=df1)

#save the plot
fig1 = sns_plot1.get_figure()
fig1.savefig("export-sns-plot.png")

pdf = FPDF(orientation = "L")

# Page 1
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image("export-sns-plot.png", x=10, y=20, w=100) # plot insert as a png file

# pdf generation     
pdf.output("add_image.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Pweave library (docs here: http://mpastell.com/pweave/). I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but with pweave you can create a pdf out of a python script or ipython notebook with plots, text and code.